# Excel returns error when raising numbers to a very large power

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm experimenting with modular arithmetic and large numbers (getting more and more into cryptography).

I'm trying to do problems along the line of 3027^253 mod 3233 and Excel is returning errors.

I thought of breaking up the problem to something along the line of

> (1000^253 mod 3233) + (1000^253 mod 3233) + (1000^253 mod 3233) +
>   (27^253 mod 3233)

but that doesn't work either. I can't get much larger than

(10^253 mod 3233) so that doesn't really help.

**It may very well be that Excel can't handle this sort of problem. If that's the case what will?**

In case it matters my programming level is low - decent javascript and basic PHP (can interact with a database).

**EDIT:**

Javascript also bugs out:

Math.pow(1000, 253);  returns Infinity. As does Math.pow(100, 253);

Comment: Have you tried using Excel's 64-bit version?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - No. Using Office 2010 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code based on the common algorithm:

```
Public Function xMod(baseV As Long, pwr As Long, modV As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    xMod = 1
    For i = 1 To pwr
        xMod = xMod * baseV
        xMod = xMod - Int(xMod / modV) * modV
    Next i
End Function
```

But, sadly, I have no idea if it is working! ..................is this what you expect ?? :

[image]

*(it does agree with the Wolfram Widget)*

Comment: Yes. I like that. Will try it.

Comment: @Mayo  Please let me know if you find a bug.

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thx.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is going to Wolfram | Alpha's [Modulo Widget](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=570e7445d8bdb334c7128de82b81fc13)

It's fast and handles these problems easily.